# What probe/tip to use to clip into a PCB test point?

Tags: pcb, probe, test-point

I need to have a digital logic analyser connected to a test point of a PCB board I'm developing for. To be clear, I mean the little ~0.5mm hole kind of test points. What kind of probe would allow me to plug into them without me having to solder it permanently, constantly manually hold it in place, or create a test point fixture?

Comment: Just get some thin wire and solder a little loop that the probe can attach to.

Answer (score 2):

For probe tip, slightly bigger than needed:

[image]

Explore here: https://www.digikey.com/products/en/test-and-measurement/test-points/616

---

If space is a problem, then have a test point and connect a small wire. Be careful with the wires and not to pull it accidentally, pulling off the test point itself from the PCB.  Put glue to secure the wires to the PCB first.

Answer (score 2):

For SMT boards, there is this style. Keystone makes several different sizes.

[image]

https://www.keyelco.com/category.cfm/Test-Points-Surface-Mount-Miniature-Compact/Miniature/p/523/id/742

Comment: I used those. Never again. They suck. shear away real easy with the leverage a long probe can have. Stick with thru hole test points. Keystone makes those to and they work great. I like this one https://www.keyelco.com/product.cfm/Ultra-Low-Profile-Style/5021/product_id/1325

Comment: I have used them on aerospace boards without any problems. Yes, you need to be careful, don't put a long scope probe on them. Use micro-clips.

Comment: Yeah microclips would be fine like the little claws on logic probes or anything of similar size where it's almost entirely hook. But any probe that has anything resembling what you would call a handle is no good.

Answer (score 0):

As Andy wrote in the comment, an option is to solder a tin wire to the hole.

Another solution is to take the cover of the probe off and measure with the bare probe. You don't need to hold it manually, you can a use a measuring stand like [this one](https://www.hahn-kolb.de/Main-Catalogue/3D-articulated-measuring-stand/1521CL04_0312030101.cyid/1521.cgid/en/US/EUR/)

Comment: In my experience a Tektronix scope probes fit nicely into 30 mil through-hole test points and will stay in place without holding them.  I assume other oscilloscope probes may be similar.